# How to give OpenVPN server on Windows access to the internet?

Tags: windows, openvpn

I've done everything from this manual:
https://gist.github.com/ViRb3/98c7cbb0b40d51c9da0965725eeef279

But it just doesn't works at all. I can connect to OpenVPN server, but can't access the internet. How do I fix that?

Comment: More information is needed. Can you please open command prompt and run `route print` on both your client and server. Paste the results in your question. Also, before you turn on internet connection sharing and any of the subsequent steps, can you confirm that you can ping the machine on the other side of the VPN link?